# How to convert string with this format to Java 8 time and convert to long milliseconds

Tags: java, java-8, datetime-format, java-time, localdate

I have a MapperUtility class that needs to map a string from a web service that sends a string time `"Fri Nov 22 2013 12:12:13 GMT+0000 (UTC)"`

Now, I am converting it to LocalDateTime with this code:

```
String time = "Fri Nov 22 2013 12:12:13 GMT+0000 (UTC)";
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ssZ");
dtf.withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
LocalDateTime convertedDate = LocalDateTime.parse(time, dtf);
```

But I am having an exception starting the GMT+0000 (UTC).
It works when I removed the characters beyond the GMT. 
After converting them to Date Time, I need to convert them to long milliseconds.
Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: How about replacing `GMT+0000 (UTC)` with `GMT` if you detect that ending to the string? Quick fix if that is one of the only edge cases.

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Comment: Hi @cameron1024 thanks for the reply. I am getting this exception: Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Fri Nov 22 2013 12:12:13 GMT+000 (UTC)' could not be parsed at index 25. Should I remove the strings beyond GMT? before converting them to milliseconds? But I am not sure if that is right approach. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may build such pattern using [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html):

```
static final DateTimeFormatter DF = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
    .appendLiteral(" GMT")
    .appendOffset("+HHmm", "+0000")
    .optionalStart()
    .appendLiteral(" (")
    .appendZoneId()
    .appendLiteral(')')
    .optionalEnd()
    .toFormatter()
    .withLocale(Locale.US);
```

Then, just:

```
String date = "Fri Nov 22 2013 12:12:13 GMT+0000 (UTC)";
long ms = OffsetDateTime.parse(date, DF).toInstant().toEpochMilli();  // 1385122333000
```

Comment: Thank you @Alex.I have followed this builder as it is the cleanest way. Thank you very much, appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

An inefficient way to make the parser accept your string verbatim is:

```
String[] timezones = {"UTC", "BST", "CET", "PST", ...};

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(timezones.length * 8 + 38);
sb.append("E MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss' GMT'Z' ('");
for(String timezone : timezones)
    sb.append("['").append(timezone).append("']");
sb.append("')'");

DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(sb.toString());
String time = "Fri Nov 22 2013 12:12:13 GMT+0000 (UTC)";
ZonedDateTime convertedDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(time, dtf);
System.out.println(convertedDate);
```

I changed to `ZonedDateTime` too because otherwise it discards the timezone and always returns 12:12:13 regardless of what's after the `GMT+`.

But it gets unwieldy pretty quick because of the inexhaustible list of possible [time zone abbreviations](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/).

A better way is to preprocess the string:

```
String time = "Fri Nov 22 2013 12:12:13 GMT+0000 (UTC)";

String preprocessed = time.replaceAll("(.*) GMT([+-][0-9]{4}).*", "$1$2");
System.out.println(preprocessed);
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ssZ");
ZonedDateTime convertedDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(preprocessed, dtf);
System.out.println(convertedDate);
```

Then the conversion to milliseconds is a bit tricky to find in the extensive `java.time` API but eventually it turns out to be as simple as:

```
convertedDate.toInstant().toEpochMilli()
```

Comment: Zone offset requires `[+-]` at the start, so the numbers are not concatenated to the seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String time = "Fri Nov 22 2013 12:12:13 GMT+0000 (UTC)";
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'xx (zzz)", Locale.ENGLISH);
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(time, dtf);
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(time, dtf);
    boolean offsetAgrees = zdt.getOffset().equals(odt.getOffset());
    if (offsetAgrees) {
        long millisecondsSinceEpoch = odt.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
        System.out.println("Milliseoncds: " + millisecondsSinceEpoch);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Offset " + odt.getOffset() + " does not agree with time zone " + zdt.getZone());
    }
```

Output:

> Milliseoncds: 1385122333000

I am parsing `GMT` as a literal, `+0000` as an offset and `UTC` as a time zone abbreviation. For the offset we could have used `xx` or `ZZZ`. Since `Fri` and `Nov` are in English, we need to specify an English speaking locale.

I have added a little complication compared to your code because we want to validate that the offset and the time zone agree. `OffsetDateTime.parse` uses the offest (`+0000`) directly whereas `ZonedDateTime.parse` derives the offset from the time zone ( `UTC`). My check is very bare-bones and may be extended to accept two possible offsets in the transition from summer time (DST) and multiple time zones sharing the same abbreviation.

PS Don’t use `LocalDateTime`. This type can neither hold an offset nor time zone, so you can no longer attach your date and time to a specific point on the time line, which you need to do to obtain milliseconds since the epoch.

Comment: Sorry that my answer has come so late. I still believed that you question deserved an answer that was a little bit simpler than the other two.